# greatest n per group multi table

Tags: php, mysql

i know there is heaps of this same question but im having trouble making it work on multiple table joins. i have 3 tables

userinfo

```
user_id | firstname | lastname
```

subnumbers

```
subnumber | fkuserid
```

transaction

```
transid | fksubnumber | expires | transdate
```

heres the part i have working

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM subtransactions
WHERE Expires < now()
ORDER BY NewSubTrans DESC) AS s
GROUP BY FKSubNum
```

What i am trying to do is select all users with a subscription that is expired. to determine if a user is expired i pull the last transaction from the transaction table with thier sub number, the fk fields are the links to the other tables.

Answer (score 2):

From your description, I don't think you need any group at all.  Try it with just these two joins:

```
SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname
FROM
 userinfo
  JOIN subnumbers ON userinfo.user_id = subnumbers.fkuserid
  JOIN transaction ON subnumbers.subnumber = transaction.fksubnumber
WHERE transaction.expires < NOW()
```

**EDIT** If it returns multiple rows as suggested in comments below, use `DISTINCT` in the select list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, firstname, lastname
  -- etc...
```

Comment: IMHO, it will return several rows per one user if one user have more than 1 subnumber and transaction

Comment: @Greenisha probably.  Easily solved with a `DISTINCT` in this instance because it isn't pulling the full subscription info -  only users.

Comment: yep, and in this case your solution is better

Answer (score 1):

This will get all user_ids

```
select distinct(user_id) from userinfo
join subnumbers on userinfo.user_id = subnumbers.fkuserid
join transaction on transaction.fksubnumber = subnumbers.subnumber
where transaction.expires < NOW()
```

To get full user data

```
select * from user where user_id in
(
select distinct(user_id) from userinfo
join subnumbers on userinfo.user_id = subnumbers.fkuserid
join transaction on transaction.fksubnumber = subnumbers.subnumber
where transaction.expires < NOW()
)
```

Comment: differs from previous - this query will return one row per user